How to display Approval Status field in a gallery or modern table control (Power Apps)
I have been having issues being able to get the value of the OOTB approval Stauts field dipslayed in my gallery or Modern table control.
Anyone experiencing this?
Can't figure out how this is being stored in SharePoint list and what control needs to be added to display it. Tried a label (But no luck -in screenshot below)

Thanks in Advance

ThisItem.'Content approval status'.Value

FredericDietrich for some reason it doesn work for me.This is the only thing that works  Text(ThisItem.'Content approval status')
